# Is this a correct translation of english to first order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

Working through first order logic examples and want to make sure I am translating correctly before moving on to harder resolution of first order logic

Use the predicates HasBugs(x), Comments(x),
HighQuality(x), QuickSolve(x), and BestPractice(x), where x is a programmer

My translations are:

#1

```
"All programmers who do not have bugs in their code and comment their code write high-quality code"

∀x(¬HasBugs(x) ∧ Comments(x) ⇒ HighQuality(x))
```

#2

```
"Programmers who use best coding practices comment their code"

∀x(BestPractice(x) ⇒ Comments(x))
```

#3

```
"Programmers who write high-quality code solve programming problems quickly."

∀x(HighQuality(x) ⇒ QuickSolve(x))
```

#4

```
"Amanda uses best coding practices and does not have bugs in her code."

BestPractice(Amanda) ∧ ¬HasBugs(Amanda)
```

#5

```
"Bill does not comment his code."

¬Comments(Bill)
```

**Note:** my main question is if I have to include a Programmer(x) predicate at all or if my use of Amanda is correct here? Or is this implied since x is a programmer?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: I agree correct.

Comment: I think it fails if $x$ is not a programmer. That's why I think it is best condition to include Programmer(x) predicate as a condition. That's my personal prefference when translating this type of sentences.

Comment: @MathStackExchange So for #3, would I write it as `∀x(Programmer(x) ⇒ (HighQuality(x) ⇒ QuickSolve(x)))`. I have a strong feeling that is wrong but im not sure how to include it correctly

Comment: @RTT Indeed, $\forall$ quantor matches with $\to$ operator in conditional contexts.